# Finding the closest true value for an index

Tags: c++, stl

Is there an elegant STL way to find the closest `true` (1) value in an array for a given index.
For example, for `std::vector<int> v{1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0};` the closest `true` value for a given index 5 is at index 6.

I tried and ended up using multiple while loops with iterators. Is it possible using C++ STL?

Comment: Are you asking for an existing algorithm searching backward and forward from a certain index to find `true` and to return the index of where it was found?

Comment: No, I'm asking if there exists a function in c++ which I overlooked.

Comment: That was what I was asking about, but perhaps a little too verbose. No, there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea that you can expand on to cover all your use-cases.

You can use [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and [std::distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) to achieve that.

Example ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/67xG37)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 };

    const auto it = std::find( std::begin(v) + 5, std::end(v), 1 );
    if ( it == std::end(v) )
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Not found!\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    const auto index = std::distance( std::begin(v), it );
    std::cout << "SUCCESS: Found at index " << index << '\n';

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can wrap your own function with your default (i.e. `true`) for better readability according to your use-case. Also, look at [std::next](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) and [std::advance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) for iterator navigation.

---

Another example using basic constructs only including some tests ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/ko_SpU)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <limits>

using Result = std::tuple<bool, std::size_t, std::string>; // result (T/F), index, message
Result find_nearest( const std::vector<int>& v, const std::size_t index, const int value )
{
    constexpr auto max_index = std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max();

    if ( v.empty() || index >= v.size() )
    {
        return { false, max_index, "Empty container or invalid index!" };
    }

    std::size_t ilhs { max_index };
    std::size_t irhs { max_index };

    for ( std::size_t i {0}; i != v.size(); ++i )
    {
        if ( v[i] == value )
        {
            if ( i < index ) { ilhs = i; }
            else if ( i > index ) { irhs = i; break; }
        }
    }

    // if element not found i.e. no index
    if ( ilhs == max_index && irhs == max_index )
    {
        return { false, max_index, "Index not found!" };
    }

    // shortest distance based comparison to determine indexes
    const auto dlhs = ( ilhs != max_index ? index - ilhs : ilhs );
    const auto drhs = ( irhs != max_index ? irhs - index : irhs );
    if ( dlhs == drhs )
    {
        return { true, ilhs, "Equal distance found! Left index returned!" };
    }

    const auto idx = ( dlhs < drhs ? ilhs : irhs );
    return { true, idx, "Index found!" };
}

int main()
{
    using Args  = std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::size_t, int>; // list, index, value
    using Tests = std::vector<Args>;

    const Tests tests
    {
        { {}, 0, 1 },
        { { 1 }, 0, 1  },
        { { 1 }, 1, 1  },
        { { 1 }, 2, 1  },
        { { 0, 0, 0 }, 1, 1 },
        { { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }, 2, 1 },
        { { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 }, 2, 1 },
        { { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 }, 3, 1 },
        { { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 }, 5, 1 },
    };

    for ( const auto& [list, index, value] : tests )
    {
        const auto& [found, idx, msg] = find_nearest( list, index, value );
        if ( found )
            std::cout << "INF: " << msg << " index: " << idx << '\n';
        else
            std::cerr << "ERR: " << msg << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ERR: Empty container or invalid index!
ERR: Index not found!
ERR: Empty container or invalid index!
ERR: Empty container or invalid index!
ERR: Index not found!
INF: Index found! index: 3
INF: Equal distance found! Left index returned! index: 0
INF: Index found! index: 5
INF: Index found! index: 4
```

Comment: I don't think your code works correctly when the ``closest`` true value appears at the left of ``index``

Comment: @szppeter: It's just an idea for the OP. The lookup on the other side and to determine the minimum distance should be a trivial task.

Comment: After some thinking, I would say it's not that trivial to take both circumstances into consideration and write in **an elegant and concise way**. Or maybe just I am dumb. Can you please show it?

Comment: @szppeter: Can you find in a range using an index to the first element?

Comment: @Azeem you may want to upvote my answer if you took over `std::find` usage instead of `std::find_if` ;)

Comment: @NutCracker: Already did! :) Thinking about changing it too. ;)

Comment: @NutCracker: Added another example: https://ideone.com/AKfamL.

Answer (score 2):

This is the most concise version I could think of.

- Use `cbegin` to find from left->right, and `crbegin()` from right->left. But notice, there need to be some calculation to get the correct starting position in the latter circumstance.

You will need **C++17** to support **if init statement**.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v{ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 };

    const int index_to_find = 5;

    int rdistance = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    if (auto iter_right = std::find(std::cbegin(v) + index_to_find + 1, std::cend(v), 1); iter_right != std::cend(v))
        rdistance = std::distance(std::cbegin(v) + index_to_find, iter_right);

    int ldistance = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    if (auto iter_left = std::find(std::crbegin(v) + v.size() - index_to_find, std::crend(v), 1); iter_left != std::crend(v))
        ldistance = std::distance(std::crbegin(v) + v.size() - index_to_find - 1, iter_left);

    if (ldistance == std::numeric_limits<int>::max() && rdistance == std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
        std::cout << "Not found!\n";
    else
    {
        if (ldistance == rdistance)
            std::cout << "Found at index: " << index_to_find + ldistance << " and " << index_to_find - ldistance << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Found at index: " << (rdistance > ldistance ? index_to_find - ldistance : index_to_find + rdistance) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: It needs some more adjustments for the left side: https://godbolt.org/z/Hk6ckJ. Try with ones only on the left e.g. `{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }`, where `i = 5`.

Comment: @Azeem Thank you, it's fixed. I forgot to adjust the starting position in ``left find`` situation.

Comment: Upvoted. You're welcome! :) A little bit more tinkering. The right side of the index is from zero but the left side is from one. Take a look at this: https://godbolt.org/z/zB4wZV.

Comment: Also, you can add `std::min()` if two indexes are found.

Comment: @Azeem Found a knowledge bug. I thought ``rbegin()`` will return the element after the last one, but it's returning the last one. I have fixed the code again.

Comment: @szppeter thanks for pointing out that my answer does not work if the index provided is e.g. `-5`. I easily fixed that now.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the most STL's and C++-ish way of solving this problem is by using the combination of [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) and, forward and reverse iterators:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int find_closest(std::vector<int> const& v, int i) {
    auto it = v.begin() + i;
    auto left_truth  = std::find(std::make_reverse_iterator(it), v.rend(), 1);
    auto right_truth = std::find(it + 1, v.end(), 1);

    auto left_distance  = std::distance(std::make_reverse_iterator(it), left_truth) + 1;
    auto right_distance = std::distance(it, right_truth);

    auto left_truth_index  = std::distance(v.begin(), --(left_truth.base()));
    auto right_truth_index = std::distance(v.begin(), right_truth);

    if (v.rend() != left_truth && v.end() != right_truth) {
        if (left_distance < right_distance) {
            return left_truth_index;
        } else {
            return right_truth_index;
        }
    } else if (v.end() == right_truth) {
        return left_truth_index;
    } else {
        return right_truth_index;
    }
}
```

You may notice that `std::make_reverse_iterator` is part of C++17 but, if you need to use C++11, you can easily make the same helper function:

```cpp
template <typename Iter>
constexpr std::reverse_iterator<Iter> make_reverse_iterator(Iter i) {
    return std::reverse_iterator<Iter>(i);
}
```

Now, you can use the `find_closest` function like this:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0};

    std::cout << find_closest(v, -6) << std::endl; // 0
    std::cout << find_closest(v, -1) << std::endl; // 0
    std::cout << find_closest(v, 0) << std::endl;  // 1
    std::cout << find_closest(v, 3) << std::endl;  // 2
    std::cout << find_closest(v, 5) << std::endl;  // 6
    std::cout << find_closest(v, 8) << std::endl;  // 7
    std::cout << find_closest(v, 10) << std::endl; // 7

    return 0;
}
```

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMRDcA7KQAOqBYXVaPUMTQV9/NTobO0cjFzcAZgBWRWVMVUCGAmZiAmDjU3MlFUjaLJyCaIdnV3cvBWzc/NDORUbK22q42uSASkVUA2JkDgByKQTbZEMsAGpxBJ11BuJMZiMF7HEABgBBCamZzHnFgDd0omJNnf3JSdppgzmFpYJXZkvrvYOHo5OdNjAEiEBAbBJbb57N5GbzCN7/AgAT28WnWxwAkm8ruCbmhaA1MAAPbzEWYNdAgECrc7EJQAfUI70%2Bi0xrk2syMzAA1pg6dTXPTGcQPiQILNWaS8LNevMPLI9rNFbNVgQhrQyQQKVTMDTBViRdidBLNhA8L0FvL9h4ACI3G62AizKi2dB06Z%2BTANCDkynnVQkF4O9l4hpSABss1OpFmDpjMvEcpuStmzAMRBjjoW1sjADoXMBbBB4zIYxak0rU%2Bn2FQCHSCMQ0whFVmNVrndoIJyeXydQLeUKDaaCP1c6sOyPOOaEpbk5XUMq8MAELX642TtmfSB2%2Bgh/MS61c5Yi9HJ2XIbtZ2n59Xa/gGiIRs2EhvNZS79kHphO9zefzaf39UuIcRxvOsGwIBBi2kWZODPC8KyvBcl1vPB70/ddWzfVCPxGIdo2IRdlzAxsp0tctFTnWZQNXCCGW0IknxfLV3wfL9TjzTAC1oY9ZgAWl4iBqPAhA82YJQi16UjyJTRCCOQ4jaJdBiW03FjPwgdj80LEc5KImjILg6S8CoWYNJzMcdxlMAwBbIS13DcND3HWZrJbXSV2E%2BNEwVZMlWM0zQLUx8XiQoigswLyZ186KVTVKjMBrBSEDorBCTg6LmxtWZlCUWUooypVYuIdV3KSlKiXSjKE1tHzMuzHLjn8syj3jZ83MIjySLy6TkyK9U7MU%2Bi0unaTquy1hcoTfLfL60LOsG1LKrqu0bTtPZY05bTutqzCQD9ZklnodlTjyg8zujbYLqumCTwu6rDJ2zc0DTf4Qu3N1WA9L0oz4sNWp0ELN0sVgLVmAB6MHZm2aSnsGTNFjel0Pq%2BggNOjXjJ1exZduB0GIahmHXxQOGsZ0J0kfdJRvou/7AaJ3Hp0VfHYMeonnvhgHsfeynPVRn6Elp7Gge0EHGfByHJEJrV2dJ8ntGRqm%2BejJJBbJ4X0FF6DxdmMMpcpGWXkR%2BWeep2YAA5VZxkXQe1jw9eJl7Da5inPsVtGYO2S31c1221vgxVZuhkbvhtUZ%2BlYEBRiSUZSFMUZthj1BI4BmQ5DJQZhmOCZOBjghI4TyTSC5dwAE4czNpJuBL7gwwSBJth4SRODDIRI%2B4GO44T0gk9GGOFBAS68/jsPSDgWAYEQYmYTwdgyAoCA0Gn2eQGAEvzGdVgsX7iAnHzmOnFsHJEUjnPSEXowtAIAB5WhWGP4fSCwTlRHYPfH7wVYMnOfuH6JdI0zGF3B0yg36sDwE4YUxBER6CwCfXOBEjBwP6DQegTA2AcB4PwMwQgRBiDkHIIQ4D%2B6QH6KgbwpQf68XJFmCQqcZCcFPsUC4gRNDaGaKYVolgqixHiGEPwAQ6DsL4REQI3CahuFaEwjIdByhNH0AUQQUjSiyI6DEcRij2hCMke0MR3QJH9AUBnEYXBw6R2jrHN%2BPdCRmzDLxMM3BZjAGQMgWYZdJCmVwIQEge4EgHj0EvVwPjJAyhTrIGQuc96F2LkkbYOYeAxKSAkMMYYS4Vw8GbbgKQI6jHbqQRBMSLEPx7n3AepAh4F1HhPCASA4beDTOQSgi9vAz1qOYTA%2BBLiCBQYwFgr9MEAHdhTeCQa3KOHdLGRwmO4/pIJZjWNsfYxxzjXE5kkBE4ehcEBrCwG4Y82Tcn5Mup3ROkcSmD0if0aJsT4nbESck1JSR0mZNGQkcZRTTllIuaMtZhSu7FM%2BRs/ouoWHcCAA%3D%3D)

Comment: If you don't validate `it` before `std::distance()`, it'll give the difference between `std::begin()` and `std::end()` even if there's no `1` on the right side of the index. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/hDVbWu.

Comment: @Azeem oh yes, you are perfectly right. I missed that in a hurry. Tnx. I will update my answer

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. You're only looking for the value on the right side. It also will not give a positive result if v[i]==true.

Comment: @Sopel Can you please elaborate on this? What will not give me the positive result? If it is possible, please share some online code with me

Comment: It returns 6 for `i=3` when a correct answer is 2. You also have UB for some values of `i` you pass.

Comment: @Sopel i guess you are right when talking about `i=3`. I was checking only the right side and didn't get what the OP really wants. I have updated my answer so please check it out now again and cast your downvote if possible

Comment: now it's just an uglier duplicate to sz ppeter's answer

Comment: @Sopel now it looks much much prettier. Let me know your opinion

Answer (score -2):

This is such a simple routine that you're best of writing a function from scratch. Just search in both directions until you hit an end on any side, and then search in just one direction.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream> 

template <typename IterT, typename ValueT>
IterT find_closest(IterT begin, IterT mid, IterT end, const ValueT& value)
{
    if (*mid == value) return mid;

    IterT lhs = mid;
    IterT rhs = std::next(mid);
    while(lhs != begin && rhs != end)
    {
        --lhs;
        if (*lhs == value) return lhs;
        if (*rhs == value) return rhs;
        ++rhs;
    }

    while(lhs != begin)
    {
        --lhs;
        if (*lhs == value) return lhs;
    }

    while(rhs != end)
    {
        if (*rhs == value) return rhs;
        ++rhs;
    }

    return end;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0};
    std::cout << &(*find_closest(v.begin(), v.begin() + 0, v.end(), 1)) - &(v[0]) << '\n';
    std::cout << &(*find_closest(v.begin(), v.begin() + 1, v.end(), 1)) - &(v[0]) << '\n';
    std::cout << &(*find_closest(v.begin(), v.begin() + 2, v.end(), 1)) - &(v[0]) << '\n';
    std::cout << &(*find_closest(v.begin(), v.begin() + 3, v.end(), 1)) - &(v[0]) << '\n';
    std::cout << &(*find_closest(v.begin(), v.begin() + 4, v.end(), 1)) - &(v[0]) << '\n';
    std::cout << &(*find_closest(v.begin(), v.begin() + 5, v.end(), 1)) - &(v[0]) << '\n';
    std::cout << &(*find_closest(v.begin(), v.begin() + 6, v.end(), 1)) - &(v[0]) << '\n';
    std::cout << &(*find_closest(v.begin(), v.begin() + 7, v.end(), 1)) - &(v[0]) << '\n';
    std::cout << &(*find_closest(v.begin(), v.begin() + 8, v.end(), 1)) - &(v[0]) << '\n';
}
```

`mid` must be dereferencable

demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66d18019fb7060f6

Comment: From the user's perspective, your function interface can't be more complicated.

Comment: So how else would you define an interface for such a function?

Comment: Well, the simplest interface from the user's perspective would be to pass in `std::vector` and index where to start from and then the function would return the index of the closest true value. It really does not make sense to return an iterator from a function.

Comment: Tell that to the whole c++ standard library. Iterators are a great generalization abstraction. Indices are not always possible to have.

Comment: From the standard's point of view it is good to use iterators, but in this case it is an overkill. For this purpose, you should keep your solution simple and stupid. Btw, did you downvote my answer?

Comment: So if you really want a super concrete solution then just define another function that uses this more generic one. Going the other way around just facilitates code duplication.

Comment: If you downvoted my answer, please let me know the reason

Comment: One more thing about the function interface: the main indicator it is overcomplicated is that when I look at it, I don't really know how to use it....

Comment: This has an interface analogical to `std::partial_sort` so I have doubts about your objectivity on that matter.